# How Do I populate a list box on a user from a range of cells in another workbook?

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

I currently am building a userform  In excel vba and I want to populate one of my list boxes. I can't get it to populate from a range of cells in another workbook? The workbook reference and sheet name are correct, I copied and tested it from a working code. I tried setting the private sub to public but I get the same results

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        Shop_UserForm_ClockIn_Listbox_EmployeeName.List = Workbooks("hub.xlsb").Sheets("EmployeeNames").Range("f2").value            
End Sub
```

This is the error message

Run-time error '381', 
Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index

Comment: As mentioned by @YowE3K, `.List` method requires array so you assign array to it. A 1D array at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is crashing because you are trying to assign a single value to the `List`.

This would work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    Shop_UserForm_ClockIn_Listbox_EmployeeName.List = Workbooks("hub.xlsb").Sheets("EmployeeNames").Range("f2:f3").value            
End Sub
```

because it is assigning an array of values.

---

If you really just want to set the `List` to a single value, you could do either of the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Shop_UserForm_ClockIn_Listbox_EmployeeName.List = Array(Workbooks("hub.xlsb").Sheets("EmployeeNames").Range("f2").value)
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Shop_UserForm_ClockIn_Listbox_EmployeeName.AddItem Workbooks("hub.xlsb").Sheets("EmployeeNames").Range("f2").value            
End Sub
```